# Server does not load/use the latest version of Extlib

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I installed the OpenNTF Essentials including the 2nd version of the 9.0.1 Extlib incl. the new mobile controls such as the Single Page App Wizard. In Domino Designer everything works fine, I can use that feature. But my server does not load/know the latest version of these Extlib bundles. Here is what it says:

```
> tell http osgi ss extlib
10.02.2014 17:20:42   Framework is launched.
10.02.2014 17:20:42   id    State       Bundle
10.02.2014 17:20:42   14    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.bazaar.codemirror_1.0.0
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=31
10.02.2014 17:20:42   25    INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
10.02.2014 17:20:42   28    RESOLVED    org.openntf.extlibx.source_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
10.02.2014 17:20:42   31    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.bazaar_1.0.0
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=14, 35
10.02.2014 17:20:42   35    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.bazaar.interpreter_1.0.0
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=31
10.02.2014 17:20:42   36    RESOLVED    org.openntf.extlib.designer.tooling.feature.source_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
10.02.2014 17:20:42   38    INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
10.02.2014 17:20:42   46    INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
10.02.2014 17:20:42   49    RESOLVED    org.openntf.extlib.feature.source_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
10.02.2014 17:20:42   251   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=252
10.02.2014 17:20:42   252   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=251
10.02.2014 17:20:42   253   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=254
10.02.2014 17:20:42   254   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=253
10.02.2014 17:20:42   255   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=256
10.02.2014 17:20:42   256   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=255
10.02.2014 17:20:42   257   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=258
10.02.2014 17:20:42   258   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=257
10.02.2014 17:20:42   259   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=260
10.02.2014 17:20:42   260   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=259
10.02.2014 17:20:42   261   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Fragments=313
10.02.2014 17:20:42   295   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   296   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   297   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   298   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   299   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   300   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   301   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   302   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   303   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   304   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   308   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.controls_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   309   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.controls_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   310   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   311   <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   312   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.oauth_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   313   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.oauth_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42                 Master=261
10.02.2014 17:20:42   314   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational.derby_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   315   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational.derby_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   316   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   317   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   318   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.sbt_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   319   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.sbt_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   320   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   321   ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
10.02.2014 17:20:42   322   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_8.5.3.20120320-1003
10.02.2014 17:20:42   323   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.0.v00_02_20130515-2200
```

If I am not wrong this output says that the server used version 9.0.1.v00_00 instead of 9.0.1.v_00_02 of the extlib bundle.

**EDIT**: Padraic Edwards asked for the following:

```
> tell http osgi diag com.ibm.xsp.extlib
10.02.2014 18:00:02   update@../../shared/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200.jar [261]
10.02.2014 18:00:02     No unresolved constraints.
```

This is my updatsite with the Essentials:
[image]

My question is: why is the latest version not activated?
My problem is that a mobile page that was created with the wizard explicitly needs the version 00_02 or higher

```
 private static final String[][] s_libraryVersions = new String[][]{
    {"com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library", "9.0.1.v00_02"},  // version of "xe:dataView infiniteScroll"
};
```

That's fine with as long as the server does what it should do.
The XSP props are set to use the "Minimum release required by the XPage featured used" setting. All other pages work well.

I even tried the version 9.0.1.v_00_03 from OpenNTF but with the same result.

BTW: the error I get reads like this (sorry, I have german LP installed):

```
Für die Seite /m_index.xsp ist "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library" Version 9.0.1.v00_02 oder höher erforderlich. Die Version der aktuellen Bibliothek lautet 9.0.1.v00_00.
```

Which means that this page needs 9.0.1_v00_02 or highter but only 9.0.1_v00_00 is installed.

**EDIT**: just noticed that the property "infitieScroll" enabled of the dataview causes the page to need this version.

Comment: Have you tried to stop the bundles and start the required bundles?

Comment: yes but encountered another problem: the 00_02 versions aren't even loaded now. I removed (backed) all 8.5.3 stuff now, signed updatesite once again and now the new versions are loaded!

Answer (score 2):

That was tricky: for some reason the old libraries (8.5.3 stuff) were loaded as well as the 9.0.1_v00_00 ones. They existed because I upraded from 8.5.3 over 9.0.0 to 9.0.1 and installed Extlib 8.5.3 before manually. I removed the old stuff (the jar files) and signed the updatesite again with my ID (though it was created and imported with the same ID here...).
Now I get the latest version as ACTIVE.
Output is now:

```
> tell http osgi ss extlib
11.02.2014 15:30:30   Framework is launched.
11.02.2014 15:30:30   id    State       Bundle
11.02.2014 15:30:30   11    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.oauth_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=49
11.02.2014 15:30:30   16    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=286
11.02.2014 15:30:30   24    <<LAZY>>    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.core_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   26    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=282
11.02.2014 15:30:30   27    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.bazaar.interpreter_1.0.0
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=67
11.02.2014 15:30:30   28    RESOLVED    org.openntf.extlib.designer.tooling.feature.source_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   30    INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   41    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.controls_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   42    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.bazaar.codemirror_1.0.0
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=67
11.02.2014 15:30:30   43    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=284
11.02.2014 15:30:30   45    RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational.derby_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   48    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=290
11.02.2014 15:30:30   49    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=11
11.02.2014 15:30:30   56    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.relational_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   58    INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.tooling_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   59    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   61    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=288
11.02.2014 15:30:30   64    RESOLVED    org.openntf.extlibx.source_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   67    ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlibx.bazaar_1.0.0
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Fragments=27, 42
11.02.2014 15:30:30   74    INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.designer.xspprops_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   76    RESOLVED    org.openntf.extlib.feature.source_9.0.1.v00_02_20131212-1115
11.02.2014 15:30:30   282   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=26
11.02.2014 15:30:30   283   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
11.02.2014 15:30:30   284   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=43
11.02.2014 15:30:30   285   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
11.02.2014 15:30:30   286   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=16
11.02.2014 15:30:30   287   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
11.02.2014 15:30:30   288   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=61
11.02.2014 15:30:30   289   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
11.02.2014 15:30:30   290   RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui.nl1_9.0.1.v00_00_20131107-0450
11.02.2014 15:30:30                 Master=48
11.02.2014 15:30:30   291   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
11.02.2014 15:30:30   292   INSTALLED   com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20131004-1200
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles over this issue and the other answer does not solve the problem:

Try to create a new UpdateSite and load the latest extlib into it. That solved the issue for me.